# Insert data into external objects

Tags: lightning-connect, salesforce-connect

I have configured a writable external object which is of type Salesforce connect : Cross-org and it uses password authentication connecting to the subscriber org. My issue is that when I synced, all fields of this external object came over as default read-only for all profiles and it is locked down such that I can't make it editable even as an admin.

Is this expected or have I configured it incorrectly?

I am unable to create new records using Database.insertAsync or Database.insertImmediate as I keep getting the error - Field is not writeable, which is understandable as the fields are read only at the profile level.

Answer (score 0):

Do not validate and sync to create the external object. Instead, manually create the external object with relevant details like the external table name and in the fields make sure the external table field names match.

DO NOT Validate and Sync; you can still see the data from the external table without syncing.